# Need to get my enum inserted into a combobox in C#

Tags: c#, enums

I need help with getting the information in my enum into a combobox.

Here is the code for my enum:

```
namespace Arsalan_Salam_991571527_A2
{
    public enum CarType
    {
        Odyssey,
        Rouge,
        Sienna,
        Accord
     }
 }
```

I have found some code that was suppose to work and I tried to implement into my code to make the information inside of enum appear as shown below:

```
   private void AddingEnumIntoComboBox(Car c)
    {
        foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CarType)))
        {
            carTypeInput.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

But for some reason the program works fine but this code does not show the information of my enum into the combobox which is called carTypeInput. This is for a college assignment.

Here is the xaml that I used to create the UI interface:

```
<Page
x:Class="Arsalan_Salam_991571527_A2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Arsalan_Salam_991571527_A2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.497,0.522">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="572,10,0,0" Text="DriveWell Inc." TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="374" Height="72"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,88,0,0" Text="Vin Number" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192" Height="67" RenderTransformOrigin="0.457,-0.751"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,185,0,0" Text="Car Make" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Height="63"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,282,0,0" Text="Car Type" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="183" Height="61"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Purchase Price"  TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="87,380,0,0" Width="226" Height="61" RenderTransformOrigin="3.948,-0.233"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,487,0,0" Text="Model Year" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="65" Width="190" RenderTransformOrigin="3.283,-2.555"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,584,0,0" Text="Mileage (Km)" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="43" Width="192"/>
    <Button x:Name="addingCar" Click="addingCar_Click" Content="Add Car" FontSize="30" Margin="43,639,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="56" Width="156"/>
    <Button x:Name="clearing" Click="clearing_Click" Content="Clear" FontSize="30" Margin="224,639,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="56" Width="134"/>
    <Button x:Name="updatingCar" Click="updatingCar_Click" Content="Update" FontSize="30" Margin="379,639,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="56" Width="130"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="carTypeInput" Margin="348,282,0,0" Width="191" Height="57"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="modelYearInput" Margin="348,483,0,0" Width="191" Height="52"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="vinNumberInput" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="348,88,0,0" Text="" FontSize="25"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="191" RenderTransformOrigin="0.476,-1.383"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="carMakeInput" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="348,185,0,0" Text="" FontSize="25"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="191"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="purchasePriceInput" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="348,380,0,0" Text="" FontSize="25"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="52" Width="191"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="mileageInput" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="348,584,0,0" Text="" FontSize="15"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="32" Width="191"/>
    <Image x:Name="carImageOutput" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="429" Margin="1013,106,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="226"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="errorMessageOutput" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="572,624,0,0" Text="" FontSize="35" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="641" Height="62"/>
    <ListView x:Name="lstCarDetailOutput" Margin="572,88,315,120"></ListView>

</Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Did you set `ItemsSource` for `Combobox`? If so, you should remove it, as this conflicts with the manual addition of items.

Comment: Do you want the name of the enum or the value (which is an integer) in the combobox?

Comment: I need the name of the enum in the combobox

Comment: Are you calling method `AddingEnumIntoComboBox` anywhere in the code?

Comment: Nope I am just using this method to add the names inside the enums into the combobox called carTypeInput

Comment: Here is the xaml as I don't know how to edit the question on this site and can you please tell how to edit the question

Comment: Creating method does not work. You also need to call the method the do it's job. You can call this method from Form_Load by doing `AddingEnumIntoComboBox(null);`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jdweng pointed this out in their comment, but I'll expand on it and make it an answer:

The problem is that `Enum.GetValues` returns the values of an enum, which is a integral type (currently C# enums are more or less a fancy wrapper around a bunch of constant numbers). By default this is a `int` (more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/enums#enum-declarations)). Meaning your call to `Enum.GetValues(typeof(CarType))` is returning `int[]`. Now there are multiple ways to get the name of an enum value, I'll demonstrate two.

1. Convert the int back to an enum value and call `ToString`

```cs
foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CarType))
{
    // This can be written as 'carTypeInput.Items.Add(((CarType) item).ToString());'
    var carType = (CarType) item;
    carTypeInput.Items.Add(carType.ToString());
}
```

2. Use `Enum.GetName` to avoid having to get an instance of `CarType`

```cs
foreach (var item in Enum.GetValue(typeof(CarType))
{
    // This can be written as 'carTypeInput.Items.Add(Enum.GetName(typeof(CarType), item));
    var carTypeName = Enum.GetName(typeof(CarType), item);
    carTypeInput.Items.Add(carTypeName);
}
```

Comment: This is still not showing the enum values in the combobox I still see the combobox blank

Comment: What GUI Framework are you using? WPF or WinForms or something else?

Comment: I'm using a UWP Blank App(Universal Windows) to create this app

Comment: So your using XAML to create your UI. Could you edit your original question to include your definition of the combobox?

Comment: Sure think, just give me a second to add the all the xaml code which I used to create the UI interface

Comment: I will post the xaml in parts

Comment: <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.497,0.522">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="572,10,0,0" Text="DriveWell Inc." TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="374" Height="72"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,88,0,0" Text="Vin Number" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192" Height="67" RenderTransformOrigin="0.457,-0.751"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,185,0,0" Text="Car Make" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Height="63"/>

Comment: Huh, are you sure your method is being called at the correct time? This seems like it should always be populated, make sure your calling your method in the constructor of your code behind class. Also, why is your method taking a parameter of type `Car c` if you don't need it?

Comment: You can Ignore that parameter as that is being used for something else

Comment: I just want to get the names that are in my enum into the combobox that is called carTypeInput to be displayed which currently not working

Comment: You haven't answered my question, are you calling `AddingEnumIntoComboBox` anywhere in your code? I.E is the method being executed?

Comment: I am not calling the method due to the reason that  I only need this method to make the names in the enum come into the carTypeInputCombobox

Comment: Also guys , you can ignore the comment of the xaml code that is in the comment as I have edited the question to add the xaml code into the question, if anyone was wandering

Comment: If you don't call a method, it won't be executed, meaning it will do nothing. If you want to have the names of the CarType enum in your combobox, you'll need to call the method, otherwise it will do nothing

Comment: Ok, can you please show how this would be accomplished

Comment: Well, when do you want to populate the combobox? I suggest you do it when the form loads, so in the constructor of your class, after `InitializeComponents()` has been called. This is easy enough and all you have to do is `AddingEnumIntoComboBox(null)`. The parameter here is null, because I don't know why that parameter is even there, as it is not needed directly in this method

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Enum.GetNames?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(CarType)));
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string carTypeName = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    
    if(carTypeName == CarType.Accord.ToString())
    {
    ...
    }
}
```